# Can't see the text inserted into a plot by Epilog

Tags: plotting

I use this command

```
ListPlot[idata27, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
  Epilog -> 
    {Inset[
       Framed[Style["Here", 20], RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> White], 
       {100, 19.6}]}]
```

to make this plot for a list of data

[image]

But I can't determine the x and y coordinates of the `Epilog` text to make it appear inside the plot. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position argument of inset is wrong. Try this

```
ListPlot[{#, #2/(# - 390)} & @@ # & /@ 
  Thread[{400 + 10 RandomInteger[10, 100], RandomReal[10, 100]}], 
Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {All, All}, Epilog -> {
  Inset[Framed[Style["Here", 20], RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> White], {440, 1/2}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Coolwater's answer works well, but there are also ways of placing an insert without having to use actual plot coordinates.

Here are some examples. I use Coolwater's data generator.

```
SeedRandom[42];
data = {#, #2/(# - 390)} & @@ # & /@ 
   Thread[{400 + 10 RandomInteger[10, 100], RandomReal[10, 100]}];
```

#### Scaled positions

When scaled positions are used, `{0, 0}` refers to the left, bottom corner of the graphics viewport and `{1, 1}` refers to the right, top corner; consequently, `{1/2, 1/2}` refers to the center. So to center the text horizontally and put it near the top of screen, we can write

```
ListPlot[data, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {All, All},
  Epilog -> 
    {Inset[
       Framed[Style["Here", 20], RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> White], 
       Scaled[{1/2, 1 - 1/8}]]}]
```

[image: plot1]

#### Named positions

Named positions are accepted as a convenience but do not give fine control. Let's try to put the text in the top-right corner of the plot with named controls. The 3rd argument of `Inset` comes into play here; without it only the lower-left quadrant of the text box would be visible.

```
ListPlot[data, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  Epilog ->
    {Inset[
       Framed[Style["Here", 20], RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> White],
       {Right, Top}, 
       {Right, Top}]}]
```

[image: plot2]

This would look good if the plot weren't framed,

```
ListPlot[data,
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  Epilog ->
    {Inset[
       Framed[Style["Here", 20], RoundingRadius -> 5],
       {Right, Top},
       {Right, Top}]}]
```

[image: plot3]

but it does't look good with a framed plot. For a framed plot, we need more control, which brings me to my next topic.

#### Mixing named and scaled positions

The problem we saw above can be fixed by using a scaled position to adjust the placement of the text. We nudges down and to the left in the plot by moving its reference point up and to right. Like so.

```
ListPlot[data,
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> All,
  Epilog ->
   {Inset[
      Framed[Style["Here", 20], RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> White],
      {Right, Top},
      Scaled[{9/8, 9/8}]]}]
```

[image: plot4]